# Некорректное описание меню метки

Tags: обсуждение, дефект, метки

Возможно проблема уже поднималась но все-таки я тоже опубликую вопрос:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я думаю нужно вместо "О компании" написать например "О метке". Но сама формулировка лично мне не нравится, могу предложить такие варианты:

1. Описание метки
2. Страница метки
3. Метка
4. Про ... (как на enSO)

Кстати немного ниже написано "О метке" - а англ версии - `Tag Info`. Это я написал к тому что, перевод заголовка нужно компоновать с данной надписью :)

Comment: Уже сто раз было...

Comment: @Qwertiy, я как-всегда вовремя :(